# $1 in curl json body now working

Tags: curl

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --request POST --url http:/myUrl.com/etc --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"myId": $1, "services": {"ENABLE_THE_SERVICE": "1"}}';
```

Then when I try to run:
./myScript.sh 77777
there is an error like:

```
{"code":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"[line: 1, column: 17] Unexpected character ('$' (code 36)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl$InputStreamWrapper@45771071; line: 1, column: 17]"}
```

Do you know how to make it work? thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't single-quote the string that contains the `$1`, that will stop the shell from expanding it.

Instead:

```sh
curl --request POST \
    --url 'http:/myUrl.com/etc' \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --data '{"myId": '"$1"', "services": {"ENABLE_THE_SERVICE": "1"}}'
```

This ends the first part of the `data` string just before the `$1`, then double quotes the `$1` itself, and concatenates that with a new single-quoted string with the rest of the data content.

This assumes that the string in `$1` is already a JSON-encoded string.  If it is not, you may want to use `jq` to construct the data payload:

```sh
curl --request POST \
    --url 'http:/myUrl.com/etc' \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --data "$( jq -nc --arg id "$1" '{"myId": $id, "services": {"ENABLE_THE_SERVICE": "1"}}' )"
```